# Reverse merge for an active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, merge

I'm facing an Rails (and finally a pur SQL) issue.

I have 3 tables (models). Event / User / Invitation

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invitations
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :events, through: :invitations
end

class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to list all events where a specific user does not have invitation.

Contraints (very important in my case):

- I'm starting my request by `Event.`

Basically, I would say it's the opposite of a merge, like a `merge.not(user.events)`.

The only solution I found is:

```
Event.where.not(id: user.events.pluck(:id))
```

But obviously, I don't like it. 2 queries that might be somehow merge into a single one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `select` instead of `pluck`, it will create sub-query instead pulling records from database. [Rails ActiveRecord Subqueries](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/23/rails-activerecord-subqueries/)

```
Event.where.not(id: user.events.select(:id))
```

Comment: This is correct! But what about the famous `NOT IN ([])` if result of the `select` is empty?  Should I check existence before? This would mean 2 queries + 1 sub query.. Can we improve that?

Comment: @brcebn Above query will take care of that and return all the events. have you tried it?

Comment: AhAh, I did now. You are still right. 